# Trouble getting my primary and foreign key to work

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I keep getting errors when I try to run the relational part of the database to pull the 3 columns in the relation table from the customer table and bill table.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS CreateDB2;
CREATE DATABASE CreateDB2;
USE CreateDB2;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_employee` (
  `tbl_EmployeeName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `tbl_Department` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `department_location` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `department_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `supervisor` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `c_ID` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `c_address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `c_Time` time NOT NULL,
  `c_order` int(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`c_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
CREATE TABLE `bill` (
  `b_items` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_discount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_deliveryFee` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_tax` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_tip` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_total` double NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`b_total`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
CREATE TABLE `food` (
  `code` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `f_catagory` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `f_item` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `f_info` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `f_price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
CREATE TABLE `restaurantinfo` (
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` int(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
CREATE TABLE `relationaltable` (
  `c_ID` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `c_order` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `b_total` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `customer` ADD CONSTRAINT `c_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`c_ID`) REFERENCES `relationaltable`(`c_ID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE `order` ADD CONSTRAINT `c_order` FOREIGN KEY (`c_order`) REFERENCES `relationaltable`(`c_order`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE `bill` ADD CONSTRAINT `b_total` FOREIGN KEY (`b_total`) REFERENCES `relationaltable`(`b_total`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

On  the last part here, it is not working. It gives error code 1005
The alter table at the bottom is the probably the issue. I am just not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Cannot add or update a child row

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key is incorrectly formed.

You connect customer.c_ID should be equal to relationaltable.c_order

```
customer.c_ID is varchar(15) NOT NULL
relationaltable.c_order is int(100) NOT NULL
```

The data type and also the length has to be matching

Comment: Please avoid greetings, signatures, etc. Please research how the site works including what makes a good post.